# Ionic framework 3, how to REPLACE a view? How to Pop() and the Push()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

> I would like to be able to replace the current view in the navigation
>   stack.

I'm designing a layout for a book which is split into 9 parts. These parts are connected together using pagination at the bottom of each part e.g. previous and next buttons.

Current structure of pages is the following: I have 1 main page (the overview) that links to all parts using `this.navCtrl.push(PartXPage)` (I've created pages for all 9 parts).
.

[image]

Each page, also links to the next and previous pages as so:

[image]

> However, here comes the problem

When I read part1, then part2, then part3 and so on, the back button always goes back 1 view at a time. So for example, if I read all the way to part 9 in 1 go and I would like to go to the overview or the main screen, I would have to click back 9 times.

What I wanted to do is create the following logic. When a user goes to the next part, we remove the current part from the view and push the next one, so the back button always returns to the overview.

I'm looking for something like (if I am on part 1, the next button would):

```
  go_to_part_2() {
    this.navCtrl.pop()  // to forget the current view
    this.navCtrl.push(Part2Page) // push a new view
  }
```

However, this code doesn't work, nor does `this.navCtrl.pop().push()`

Comment: try `this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => { this.navCtrl.push(Part2Page) })`

Comment: @GregDan This is exactly what I need functionality-wise, however, it looks like I can see the whole transition to the main page and back which could be very slow on old devices. Any way to improve this?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/ navoptions -animate boolean Whether or not the transition should animate.

Comment: @GregDan Thanks, I added this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => { this.navCtrl.push(Chapter1Part1Page,{animate : false} )}), however, it seems to still show the animation for pop, hence I can see the overview page appearing for a split second before navigating away

Comment: so add nav options to pop call https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#pop RTFM   :)

Comment: there are also other interesting nav controller apis like remove and removeView

Comment: You can use `this.navCtrl.remove(index)` after push new page. But, why don't you just create a home button?

Comment: @Duannx Thanks! And due to styling issues, I didn't want to create more buttons than necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom back button from ionic in navigation bar and after that when user click on back button you can set the Root page whatever you want to show to user

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(PageName)`

Comment: If I do this before pushing pages, the reading list becomes a root page, and I can't go back to the main menu. The back button disappears from Image 1.